# Weird:not able to add 2 columns TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, string, int, addition

both are float. I am trying to add 2 columns, but i am not able to. studied but cant find explanation.

```
min100['Cost']=min100['JCP']+min100['MAX_JC']
```

but, I am receiving following error. Please tell me, what I am doing wrong.

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Following information may be helpful to remove this error

```
result=min100['MAX_JC'].dtypes
print(result)
```

MAX_JC    float64
MAX_JC    float64
dtype: object

```
result=min100['JCP'].dtypes
print(result)
```

float64

I found a weirdest work around

```
      min100['Cost2']=min100['MAX_JC']+1
      min100['Cost']=min100['JCP']+min100['Cost2']-1
```

But please tell why lower code is working and not the first one.
One more info may be useful is that I got min100['MAX_JC'] using the code below

```
min100['MAX_JC'] = min100.max(axis=1)
```

Comment: Perhaps you can print the values themselves, like `print(min100['MAX_JC'])` and `print(min100['JCP'])`.  That may help to see what values are being added.

Comment: Hi user212514, I found a weirdest work around. please check the edited post